# Invalid method addFieldToSelect

Tags: database, collection, model, collection-filtering

I have this code

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("news/views");
->addFieldToSelect('post_id', array('eq' =>  $this->getRequest()->getParam("id")));
```

And when i'm trying to save my post i get en error:

> Invalid method Iv_News_Model_Views::addFieldToSelect(Array ( [0] =>
>   post_id [1] => Array ( [eq] => 13 ) ) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `addFieldToSelect` is available for collection objects. It is defined in `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract` so it is available in all its child classes.

You are calling it on a model object that most probably is a child of `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`.

I think you meant to do this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("news/views")->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToSelect('post_id', array('eq' =>  $this->getRequest()->getParam("id")));
```

Comment: it gets  Fatal error: Call to a member function addFieldToSelect() on a non-object

Comment: This means that you module is not properly built. For a CRUD module you need a model, a resource model and a collection model. Most probably you are missing the collection mode.

Comment: Ok i figure it out that i have file Collections.php insted of Collection.php. What a rookie mistake. Thanks Marius.

Comment: One more question. Can I delete such collection ?

Comment: @user3245106. What do you mean by "delete such collection"?

Comment: `$collection->delete();` -  I wan to delete all items with my post_id

Comment: `$collection = ...; foreach ($collection as $item){$item->delete()}`

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `iv_news_store` AS `main_table`' at line 1`

Comment: This may depend on how your module is built. In general this is the way to delete things.

Comment: This error is related with foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

According to problem from comment the soulution was to change

```
AddFieldToSelect()
```

to

```
AddFieldToFilter()
```

and it worked.